# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flexigrid

I am trying to obtain a cell's text value from a flexigrid.
However I keep getting that error.

This is my function for retrieving a specific cell's text(Flexigrid doesnt have "attr" it has "abbr" instead).

```
function getSelectedCopyDates() {
    var arr = new Array();
    debugger;
    //for every row that has a checked checkbox
    $("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this.id) !== "checkAllNotes") {
            //push the value of column(FName, LName) into the array 
            arr.push($("#" + this.id + "> td[abbr='EventDate'] > div").text());
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
```

I only get that error when I click on "checkAllNotes"(main check box ). If I check a checkbox manually then everything works fine.

Here is my flexigrid layout:

```
$('#viewNotesGrid').flexigrid({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    colModel: [{
        display: '<input type="checkbox" class="noteCheckBox" id="checkAllNotes" />',
        name: 'checkBox',
        width: 20,
        sortable: false,
        align: 'center',
        process: showDescription
    }, {
        display: 'Date',
        name: 'EventDate',
        width: 80,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'center',
        process: showDescription
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st problem is that `$("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked")` returns tr elements, not input checkboxes.

2nd problem: `$(this.id) !== "value"` will never work. You are creating jQuery object and comparing it with string. Should be `this.id !== "value"`

3rd problem: already explained in previous answer. If  element doesn't seem to have id, then `"#" + this.id + ">` would result in `"#>"`, and you actually want to compare id of special input field, not tr.

Making few assumptions here, but this might work:

```
function getSelectedCopyDates() {
var arr = new Array();

//for every row that has a checked checkbox
$("tr .noteCheckBox:checked").each(function (i) {
    if (this.id !== "checkAllNotes") {
        var tr = $(this).parents("tr")[0]; // going back to parent tr
        arr.push($(tr).find(" > td[abbr='EventDate'] > div").text());
    }
});
return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not very familiar with jQuery. This however explains a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to use `this.id ==` vs. `$(this.id) ==`.  It also seems like the error may be because `this.id` is empty (jQuery will throw that error on `$("#>")`, but the error message also seems to include the `>`, so I'm not sure).

Comment: how could it throw an exception on an empty string if I am iterating through the selected rows. I mean the function I have without the if statement  works perfectly fine except for when I tick the "id=checkAllNotes" checkbox.

Comment: @user1084319 don't know; I guess one of the rows is missing an id?

Comment: ah but the thing is the rows don't have id's. only the checkbox called "checkAllNotes" has an id. All the other checkboxes just have attirbute ids (abbr not attr since its a flexigrid). the "checkAllNotes" has a class thought that is the same with all the other checkboxes.